# Human-readable output with DEAP

Tags: python, deap

I am using DEAP to do symbolic regression on a table of data, i.e. finding a function that best fits the data. Unfortunately, I can't find a way of getting the result in human-readable format. For instance, if I do

```
best_ind = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
print("Best individual is %s" % (best_ind))
```

my output is likely to look something like

```
Best individual is add(mul(add(x, 2), div(y, add(x, y))), 1)
```

but that is difficult for a human to interpret. Is there a way to print the result in a way that looks more like

```
(x+2)*(y/(x+y))+1
```

Comment: Inherit from `tools` and overload `def __str__()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with using `sympy.simplify`

```
import sympy

expr = "Add(x, 2)"
sympy.simplify(expr)  # x + 2
```

However, sympy wants add, mul etc capitalized. Also You need to translate `Div(a, b)` to `Mul(a, 1/b)`.

You can do this by changing the `primitive.format` method like so:

```
def convert_inverse_prim(prim, args):
    """
    Convert inverse prims according to:
    [Dd]iv(a,b) -> Mul[a, 1/b]
    [Ss]ub(a,b) -> Add[a, -b]
    We achieve this by overwriting the corresponding format method of the sub and div prim.
    """
    prim = copy.copy(prim)
    prim.name = re.sub(r'([A-Z])', lambda pat: pat.group(1).lower(), prim.name)    # lower all capital letters

    converter = {
        'sub': lambda *args_: "Add({}, Mul(-1,{}))".format(*args_),
        'div': lambda *args_: "Mul({}, Pow({}, -1))".format(*args_)
    }
    prim_formatter = converter.get(prim.name, prim.format)

    return prim_formatter(*args)
```

This code is taken from [glyph](https://github.com/Ohjeah/glyph/blob/4f19742fe771f91208bbbe786e22157e6ed4aeed/glyph/gp/individual.py#L371-L416).

Answer (score 3):

Ohjeahs answer does not work as provided. I modified the code provided and provided it below.

```
import sympy
def convert_inverse_prim(prim, args):
    """
    Convert inverse prims according to:
    [Dd]iv(a,b) -> Mul[a, 1/b]
    [Ss]ub(a,b) -> Add[a, -b]
    We achieve this by overwriting the corresponding format method of the sub and div prim.
    """
    prim = copy.copy(prim)
    #prim.name = re.sub(r'([A-Z])', lambda pat: pat.group(1).lower(), prim.name)    # lower all capital letters

    converter = {
        'sub': lambda *args_: "Add({}, Mul(-1,{}))".format(*args_),
        'protectedDiv': lambda *args_: "Mul({}, Pow({}, -1))".format(*args_),
        'mul': lambda *args_: "Mul({},{})".format(*args_),
        'add': lambda *args_: "Add({},{})".format(*args_)
    }
    prim_formatter = converter.get(prim.name, prim.format)

    return prim_formatter(*args)

def stringify_for_sympy(f):
    """Return the expression in a human readable string.
    """
    string = ""
    stack = []
    for node in f:
        stack.append((node, []))
        while len(stack[-1][1]) == stack[-1][0].arity:
            prim, args = stack.pop()
            string = convert_inverse_prim(prim, args)
            if len(stack) == 0:
                break  # If stack is empty, all nodes should have been seen
            stack[-1][1].append(string)
    return string

sympy.simplify(stringify_for_sympy(best_ind))
```

Comment: The original commenter asked how to convert the output from deap to something that could be read by a person. An answer was provided but it was wrong, i went ahead and fixed that error and posted the resulting code. I think that there may have been a lack of clarity from my original statement that insinuated I was asking a new question. I have gone ahead and modified it.

Answer (score 0):

This tiny one works well for me:

```
from sympy import sympify

locals = {
    'sub': lambda x, y : x - y,
    'div': lambda x, y : x/y,
    'mul': lambda x, y : x*y,
    'add': lambda x, y : x + y,
    'neg': lambda x    : -x,
    'pow': lambda x, y : x**y,
}

# ind = 'div(add(div(x, mul(y, y)), 1), mul(x, y))'
print(f'original: {ind}')
expr = sympify(str(ind) , locals=locals)
print(f'simplified: {expr}')
```

The output:

```
original: div(add(div(x, mul(y, y)), 1), mul(x, y))
simplified: (x/y**2 + 1)/(x*y)
```

It does even show the LaTex from when displayed inside a Jupyter notebook:

```
display(expr)
```

[image]